# Разрешить выделение строки(ячейки) при отключенном редактировании

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml, datagrid

С DataGrid имеется следующая проблема -  DataGrid имеет IsReadOnly="False" Но мне необходимо некотрые ячейкит и строки сделать нередактируемыми, но доступными для выделения. Для DataGridCell и DataGridRow у меня не получилось установить программно запрет на редактирование через IsReadOnly.Получилось сделать запрет на редактирование через IsEnabled, но тогда я не могу выделить ячейку(строку), даже если устанавливаю явно row.IsHitTestVisible = true:

```
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator
                                                   .ContainerFromIndex(1);
        row.IsEnabled = false;
        row.IsHitTestVisible = true;
```

Как можно программно запретить редактирование, но не запретить выделение ячейки или строки?

Comment: Похоже что это невозможно. Возможность редактирования задается либо на уровне всей DataGrid, либо на уровне отдельных столбцов (при их создании). Выход - запретить редактирование на уровне всей таблицы и предусмотреть отдельное представление для редактирования сущностей

Answer (score 0):

Один из костыльных вариантов - внутренность каждый ячейки сделать TextBox и у них по строкам или столбцам `IsEnabled = false.` В итоге не может редактировать TextBox, можем редактировать Ячейку(но там TextBox, поэтому не может) и можем выделять так же строку, ячейки и столбцы(т.к мы влияем на внутренне содержимое, а не сами строи и столбцы).

Но это крайний костыль как по мне.